# Laravel dynamic select box return index instead of value from collection

Tags: forms, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a select box that return value from $collection, but it gives me index of the selection instead of value.

[screenshot:output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU5bo.png)

[screenshot:browser source code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c9E2.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('Supervisor') !!}<br />
   {!! Form::select('supervisor_id', $lecturers, null, 
    array('placeholder' => '----------------','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
```

and when it's show in browser source code view:

```
<option value="">----------------</option>
<option value="0">1111111111</option>
<option value="1">1212121212</option>
```

Anyone who know the syntax of laravel form to make this dynamic form gives value of $lecturers please help.

Comment: What's your code for storing into db?

Comment: @DoIGetAnything just updated with source code view,I think the source code above proved this isnt backend problem

Comment: Storing in DB is back-end problem. You said you want store `value`, but it stores `key`

Comment: By the way, `<option value="0">1111111111</option>` this stores `0` in DB because of `value="0"`. Change to `<option value="1111111111">something here</option>` and it stores `1111111111`

Comment: Is there any way to get the same output by using Laravel build in form helper?

Comment: What is _same output_? Provide any php code!

Comment: I meant using {!! Form::select !!} to achieve what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here we go.

First in your controller, when you are getting the lecturers list, make sure you pluck just the name and the id...in this order:

```
$lecturers = Lecturer::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Then in your view:

```
{{Form::select('lecturer_id', $lecturers, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Thats all.

The array of lecturers, that you plucked will be divided into "id" and "values", hence the order of plucking is important.

Now, in your form source, you will see that the option value will be lecturers ids like "1, 2, 3" etc while the "selectable" options shown to users will be the names of the lecturers.

Like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="lecturers_id"><option value="1">John Doe</option><option value="2">Jane Doe</option></select>
```

Try these and lets know your result.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I actually seen same guides on many websites but all of those author didnt mention the importance of order of plucking and how it works in dynamic select box. Your answer cleared my doubts. THANKS